# Can we use for loop for items of a struct?

Tags: swift

I have a struct like this:

```
struct TestType {
    var value1: String? = "1"
    var value2: String? = "2"
    var value3: String? = "3"
    var value4: String? = "4"
    var value5: String? = "5"
    var value6: String? = "6"
    var value7: String? = "7"
    var value8: String? = "8"
    var value9: String? = "9"
}
```

I want be able to use a for loop on values of TestType, like this code in below, is this possible in swift?

Or even any kind of loop support for items of a struct?

```
func myTestFunction() {
    let test: TestType = TestType()
    test(value1...value9).forEach { value in
        if let unwrappedValue: String = value {
            print(unwrappedValue)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Theoretically you could use reflection, but it’s probably better to just change your model an iterable collection (i.e. an array of strings, e.g. `[String]`).

Comment: Yes not bad, but I really love to access items like test.value1, test.value2, ... instead of test[0], test[1].

Comment: There are a bunch of approaches that could do what you want. E.g., make the model an array or dictionary and then have computed properties to retrieve and set the individual items in the collection; make the model a series of independent properties, and then have computed property which returns an array of them in a particular order; an case-iterable enumeration of keypaths; etc. We probably need more details and/or a practical example that reflects the specifics of your use-case, to advise further.

Comment: You almost helped me even without knowing the real code, I was aware to using dic but did not thought about using computed property with it, thanks.

Comment: If this that’s been resolved and you are not going to provide more information on what you want to achieve or how you resolved your issue then please remove the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Mirror` to achieve that, something like this:

```
struct TestType {
    var value1: String? = "1"
    var value2: String? = "2"
    var value3: String? = "3"
    var value4: String? = "4"
    var value5: String? = "5"
    var value6: String? = "6"
    var value7: String? = "7"
    var value8: String? = "8"
    var value9: String? = "9"
    
    func iterateThroughProperties() {
        for property in Mirror(reflecting: self).children where property.label != nil {
            print("name: \(property.label!)")
            print("value: \(property.value)")
            print("type: \(type(of: property.value))")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that was what I was looking for, should we as developer avoid using Mirror? Is it any side effect or risks to use Mirror in our daily base coding?

Comment: I think no. Just be careful when you do changes inside your struct. The result of the method may change. It will be better to cover your struct with unit tests. Thats it)

Answer (score 0):

```swift
[String?](mirrorChildValuesOf: TestType())
```

```swift
public extension Array {
  /// Create an `Array` if `subject's` values are all of one type.
  /// - Note: Useful for converting tuples to `Array`s.
  init?<Subject>(mirrorChildValuesOf subject: Subject) {
    guard let array =
      Mirror(reflecting: subject).children.map(\.value)
      as? Self
    else { return nil }

    self = array
  }
}
```